# Jquery mobile - select menu modificate value after change

Tags: jquery, select, mobile

I'm creating my new application, it's a jQuery mobile framework application. I'm using ajax to load multiple of selects with options.

For example I create an element in code:

```
var select = $('<select name="someSelect" data-placeholder="false" class="select-additional" data-native-menu="false" />');
```

And then I have a ajax call, and I save objects to var ajaxItems, I make a loop and add the options to the select.

```
for(var i in ajaxItems){
   val option = $('<option val="'+ajaxItems[i].val+'">'+ajaxItems[i].val+' Days</option>');
   select.append(option);
}
```

And now, everything is ok, jQuery render the page with selects, and it looks good.

But I have a problem:

I want to make something like that: When user click on select, option value must be set as string in select, default the text of option is set, but i want a value, for example if user click on option:

```
<option value="1">1 day</option>
```

I want to make select string as 1, not as 1 day, because I have a very small select inputs, and unit (days) is not important...

jQuery mobile rendered code:

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <a href="#select-27-listbox" role="button" id="select-27-button" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-rel="popup"><span class="select-additional">4 Tage</span></a>
    <select data-native-menu="false" data-id="4084" data-icon="false" data-theme="a" class="select-additional" data-placeholder="false" tabindex="-1">
       <option value="0">0 </option>
       <option value="1">1 Tag</option>
       <option value="2">2 Tage</option>
       <option value="3">3 Tage</option>
       <option value="4">4 Tage</option>
       <option value="5">5 Tage</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And im trying to make something like that:

```
$('ui-select').change(function(
   $(this).prev().find(span.select-additional).text($(this).val());
));
```

But it not make a change in label, i have a 90% certainty, i making its ok, when in log the object `$(this).prev().find(span.select-additional).text()`, its showing me a value, but value before change! For ex if I pick up 1, it's showing 0, then when I pick up 2, it's showing 1.

I think the problem is: I'm trying to change value, but before jQuery mobile does that, and jQuery mobile overwrites my text...

I know its possible because I saw it on another jQuery mobile page, but I need some callback after jQuery set the value... Or some delay?

Comment: Strange, on jsFiddle its working... http://jsfiddle.net/kudej/6gK44/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the answer.
I saw the problem is on the other pages, on first everything was ok, and my method give a effect.
But on another pages, there is no effect, the solution a make code on page create:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
            $('select').change(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var element = $(this);
                element.prev().find('.select-additional').text(value);
            });
});
```